# Drupal REST return 301 after logging in from ionic application

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, drupal-7, token, http-status-code-301

I have web application based on drupal 7, and I want to create ionic app connected with that web app using REST.

Login action work good, but after login I always get status 301 Moved Permamently, no matter what I call from REST.

But when I do the same using ARC or POSTMASTER all works good. I can call login successfully, get token successfully, and logout without any problem.

I guess the reason is not set header properly. When I use ARC or POSTMASTER my request contains Cookie with session_name and sessid received from drupal during login.
Also I cant set X-CSRF-Token in header.
But when I attempt to set it on angular nothing changes on request [headers are not set].

My login controller on ionic(angular):

```
var login = function(name, pw) {    
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {

        var data = "username="+name+"&password="+pw;
        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
            }
        }

        $http.post('http://example.com/user/login.json', data, config)
            .then(
                function(response){
                // success callback
                storeUserCredentials(name + '.' + response.data.token, response.data.session_name, response.data.sessid);
                storeUserRole(response.data.user.roles);

                resolve('Login success.');
                }, 
                function(response){
                    // failure callback
                    //console.log('error '+response);
                    reject('Login Failed.');
                }
        );

    });
};
```

My logout controller on ionic(angular):

```
var logout = function() {

    var data = "username="+name+"&password="+pw;
    var config = {
        headers : {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
            'X-CSRF-Token': token,
            'Cookie':session_name + '=' + sessid
        }
    }

    $http.post('http://example.com/user/logout.json', data, config)
        .then(
            function(response){
                // success callback
                destroyUserCredentials();
            }, 
            function(response){
                // failure callback
                destroyUserCredentials();
        }
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**This technique works for me**

I store the 'minimal' config object as a starting point.  This object is created using the response from `/services/session/token` as the `data` in the following:

```
localStorageService.set('HTTP_CONFIG', {
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRF-Token': data
    }
});
```

Contrary to many examples online, I find it unnecessary to set the cookies manually.  In fact, attempting to set cookies often results in errors.  In this example I'll use local storage to produce copies of the http config.

---

Next, I ascertain if I'm logged in or not.

```
var tokenConfig = localStorageService.get('HTTP_CONFIG');
tokenConfig.url = APP_CONFIG.REST_API + '/system/connect.json';
tokenConfig.method = 'POST';
tokenConfig.data = {};
$http(tokenConfig) ...
```

---

I simply carry forward in this manner, for instance:

```
var loginConfig = localStorageService.get('HTTP_CONFIG');
loginConfig.method = 'POST';
loginConfig.url = APP_CONFIG.REST_API + '/user/login';
loginConfig.data = { username: username, password: password };
$http(loginConfig) ...
```

---

I simply carry forward using the same 'minimal' http config object, adding properties as required.  This has worked perfectly for me.